# Can't fix 'IdentityUserLogin<string> requires primary key' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

So i have two contexts and i'm using mycontext but i keep getting errors even when mycontext inherits from IdentityDbcontext. I've tried various fixes i found here but none has worked

I used ApplicationUser as the defaultidentity in startup. But to no avail

[My-context]
`

```
public partial class MyContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public HMyContext()
        {
        }

        public HRMSDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }`
[Startup]
`services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>();
```

'

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
```

InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model)...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you should be passing on the options to the base constructor so:

```
    public MyContext()
    {
    }
```

needs to pass on options to base constructor like so.

```
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```